# Каким лучше образом пропарсить сайт без API?

Tags: php, парсер

У меня есть сайт с торговой площадкой, мне нужно его пропарсить средствами php (есть ли какие то библиотеки).

1. Проблема 1: Для того что бы перейти на эту страницу нужно
   авторизоваться.
2. Проблема 2: Сам парсинг HTML кода.
3. Проблема 3: Запуск скрипта раз в час

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Авторизация через curl
2. Парсинг через:

*) регулярные выражения

*) через библиотеки PHP, например:

```
PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser
PHPQuery
Zend_DOM_Query
Nokogiri
```

*) Или через js, например:

```
PhantomJS
CasperJS
SlimerJS
Zombie.js
```

*) Python:

```
lxml
BeautifulSoup
Grab
html5lib
HTMLParser
pyQuery
xml.dom.minidom
Leaf
mechanize
```

*) + на иных языках

3. Запуск через крон скрипта парсинга/обновления